# How to create a graph from a remote file?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, igraph

I am trying to read a graph from a remote file hosted on aws s3 using python-igraph. I know I could save the file locally, but the goal is to run this code using AWS Lambda. That way I would like to read the file and create the graph without using local memory.

I can read a local file and create a graph from it. However, I cannot read the same file remotely.

```py
import s3fs
import igraph as ig

BUCKET_NAME = "my_aws_bucket"
s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False, key='my_key', secret='my_secret')

# LOCAL FILE

fr = 'local_path'
f = open(fr)
print(f)
g = ig.Graph.Read_Ncol(f, directed=False)

# REMOTE FILE

f2 = s3.open(BUCKET_NAME + 'remote_path', "r")
print(f2)
g = ig.Graph.Read_Ncol(f2, directed=False)
```

The result of the prints are:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='../files/network_Melan.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
<_io.TextIOWrapper encoding='UTF-8'>
```

However, the second part (remote file) gives Segmentation fault. Can someone help me?